# How to reduce the reserved memory that is not currently being used in an array in C?

Tags: c, memory-management

Let's say we reserved 32 bytes for an array in C, but it turns out we are only using 24 bytes, how can I reduce the reserved memory that is not currently in use? Is this even possible?

I am not using malloc, but I could.

This is the working minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
 
    FILE *input;
    input = fopen("1.txt", "r");

    int arr[4][300];

    if (input == NULL) {
       printf( "ERROR. Coundn't open the file.\n" ) ;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
            fscanf(input, "%d %d %d %d", &arr[0][i], &arr[1][i],
                    &arr[2][i], &arr[3][i]);
        }
        fclose(input);

        int sze = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
             for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                if (abs(arr[j][i]) >= 1)
                    sze += log10(abs(arr[j][i])) + 1;
                else
                    sze++;

                if (arr[j][i] < 0)
                   sze++;
             }
        }
        printf("Size %d kB\n", sze);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Clarification: What I need is to reduce the memory used by each element in the array, if possible. Let's say I have the number 45 stored, it doesn't take up all 4 bytes of an int, so I need to reduce the memory allocated to only 1 byte. As I said, I am not currently using malloc, but I could switch to malloc, if there's a way to what I want to.

Comment: Depends how the memory was allocated. Can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: It is not possible.

Comment: array sized cannot be changed.

Comment: However, if you had allocated the memory with [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc), then you could change the size of the allocation using the function [`realloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc).

Comment: @AndreasWenzel so why did you encourage David to delete his answer?

Comment: @0____: It was not my intention to encourage David to **delete** his answer, but rather to notify him that the question has been substiantially changed, so that his answer no longer directly corresponds to the question. I thought that he may want to take appropriate action, such as to adapt the wording of his answer to the changed question. I did not expect him to simply delete his answer.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel What I need to reduce is not the total size of the array, but the memory used up by each single element. (see clarification) Is this possible with realloc? I have been reading about it but couldn't find a way.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Change the size from 32 to 24? Allocate exactly as much memory as needed to handle the problem, no more, no less.

Comment: @Lundin I  am reading data from a file, I don't how much memory these numbers will take up beforehand.

Comment: Then design for the worst case. Write a specification of how many numbers you will handle.

Comment: Your problem seems to be similar to encoding [UNICODE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) character values, which can have values up to 144,697, into a variable number of bytes. For example, [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is designed in such a way that the value is encoded into one byte, if the value is between 0 and 127, but for higher values, it is encoded in two, three or sometimes even four bytes. The [most-significant bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering#Bit_significance_and_indexing) of the first byte specifies whether the value consists of one byte or more.

Comment: I generally don't recommend that you do this, though, because even if you save a bit of space, it will make your code a lot more complicated and slower, because it will be a lot of work for the CPU to uncompress the data. However, if you want to archive large amounts of data, then it can be meaningful to compress the data, to save some space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reduce the used space for a value, you need to assign it to an object of different type.

In your example, you start with an `int` that probably uses 4 bytes on your system. Then you store the value "45" in it, which needs just one byte. Types with size of 1 byte are for example `int8_t` or `signed char`.

First, you cannot change the type of a variable, once it is defined. You may store it in *another* variable.

Second, all elements of an array have to be of the same type.

So the answer for the given example is simply "**No.**"

If you want to "compress" the stored values, you need to roll your own type. You can invent some kind of "vector" that stores each value in as few bytes as necessary. You will need to store the size of each value, too. And you will need to implement access function to each vector element. This is not a simple task.